# Conflict between two different tableview xCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I've got serious problem with two of my tableview being side by side. I made an interface where I can see folders (named as Collection) and if a tap on a button it shows me informations about data (named as Likes).

But, I don't really understand why many methods works and cellForRowAtIndexPath don't.
Here is where the problem is :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   if (tableView == _collectionTableView)
```

So, this if just doesn't work. He got me to sigabrt everytime. Because My all functions have 3 choices :
If you are _collectionTableView, there you go. Else if you are "_LikesTableView", there you go, ELSE there it's nil.

BUT, If I take the _LikesTableView to be the first choice, all works except it will send me that I am _LikesTableView, even if the others methods like :

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Get me as _CollectionTableView ... So my logs are pretty funny It goes from "I am _CollecTableView" to "I am _LikesTableView" only for the cellForRowAtIndexPath.

It's pretty annoying that I can't get my _CollectionTableView to work properly, while my _LikesTableView seems to work very well if it goes in the "if" in place of the "else if".

So I suppose that I don't use the method very well, of that my If shouldn't mention the name of my tableview in this method... So, if anyone is able to help me, it would be really, really, really appreciated !

Thanks a lot. 
EDIT : The famous logs:

```
2014-08-14 11:40:07.269 [TestLog] Je le prend bien en compte le collectableview
2014-08-14 11:40:07.269 [TestLog] Je le prend bien en compte le collectableview
2014-08-14 11:40:07.270 [TestLog] Je le prend bien en compte le collectableview
2014-08-14 11:40:07.842 [TestLog] Je passe bien dans le cellforrow
2014-08-14 11:40:07.843 [TestLog] Je suis LikesTableView
2014-08-14 11:40:07.950 [TestLog] Je passe bien dans le cellforrow
2014-08-14 11:40:07.951 [TestLog] Je suis LikesTableView
2014-08-14 11:40:08.070 [TestLog] Je passe bien dans le cellforrow
2014-08-14 11:40:08.070 [TestLog] Je suis LikesTableView
2014-08-14 11:40:08.191 [TestLog] Je passe bien dans le cellforrow
2014-08-14 11:40:08.191 [TestLog] Je suis LikesTableView
2014-08-14 11:40:08.286 [TestLog] Je passe bien dans le cellforrow
2014-08-14 11:40:08.287 [TestLog] Je suis LikesTableView
2014-08-14 11:40:08.355 [TestLog] Je passe bien dans le cellforrow
2014-08-14 11:40:08.356 [TestLog] Je suis LikesTableView
2014-08-14 11:40:08.428 [TestLog] Je passe bien dans le cellforrow
2014-08-14 11:40:08.429 [TestLog] Je suis LikesTableView
2014-08-14 11:40:08.502 [TestLog] Je passe bien dans le cellforrow
2014-08-14 11:40:08.502 [TestLog] Je suis LikesTableView
```

Hope that could help >____<"

Comment: did you checked the link between the tableView and the associated property ? Could you paste more code ?

Comment: My two tableView are linked to their variable if it's what you mean, and the two have their Delegate and Datasources to my ViewController, that's why my LikesTableView works. And yes, I can do it but... What to paste? /: The problem comes from this method at this verification so... I don't really know what could help much.

Comment: <waffling>Ah, un français ! Salutations. Je continue en anglais, histoire d'être compréhensible par la majorité...</waffling>
Can't you past the whole delegate methods' content or the entire project ? A radical solution would be to get one tableView in first view, and the other into a second view. Moreover, it's certainly more ergonomic.

Comment: Yes, it's kind of what I think, but all the delegate methods are done in the Storyboard, I just get the content in cells in the code (if you're talking about DataSources and Delegate things). < Oui! Un français qui galère un peu avec Xcode, pas facile au début! > But I've got the solution sooo... thanks for your help though!

Comment: Yep, XCode et Objective-C ne sont pas supers faciles à appréhender. Mais une fois qu'on est dedans, j'avoue que c'est un environnement plutôt sympa...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about consider using tag for your tableView.

First set tag of your collectionTableView at where you initialised it, for example viewDidLoad

```
_collectionTableView.tag = 1;
```

and at your cellForRowAtIndexPath, instead of   `if (tableView == _collectionTableView)` , use tag to check which tableView is calling the method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if (tableView.tag == 1)
   {
    ///do something
   }
   else
   {
    ///do something
   }
}
```

Comment: I just tried it and, I don't really know if it's linked but now I have the information that the flag stays at 1 for the time he check the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, and get to 2 after this. I have set the flag to 1 for my LikeTableView and to 2 for my CollecTableView, in the viewDidLoad.

Comment: You will need to assign different tag number for all tableViews in the same viewController to prevent conflict if the dataSource and delegate are set to the same class. In your datasource and delegate methods, simply check the tag of the tableView returned then feed the data accordingly.

Comment: I think that the part of my mate codes is a little mess... It doesn't really work but, I'll try to rethink the tableView with you solution, thanks a lot, you save me lot of time searching for a flag to set on my views!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Casey's approach of using tags for comparison. 
Also you could have a separate data source for each table view, just to avoid confusion, if it is possible in your design. So another class which conforms to UITableViewDataSource should be created. This new class can be assigned as the dataSource for one of the tableView's.

Comment: It's what i'm afraid of... My mate sort of make the two tableViews in the same class with similar properties... Thanks for the tips, i'll try without rebuilding all the ViewController and... If I'm not able to get it work after that, i'll do different classes as you suggest, thanks!